# Display a video using imgui

Tags: c++, video, gstreamer, display, imgui

I'm trying to create an interface that would allow me to drive a remote controlled car.

I was wondering if it were possible to display a video using ImGui ? I know I can split my video into several frames and display each frames one after the other but is there any other way to do this ?
Thank you !

Comment: IMGUI is an architecture for UI libraries. It has nothing to do with displaying videos, or images for that matter. It would be unusual to find an application that drew all its graphics via some IMGUI-implementing library.

Comment: I originally wanted to use Qt but it raises some issues with the licenses. I had planned to use the gstreamer library to get the video stream and display it with openGL and ImGui. What do you advise me to use instead ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to display a video in dear ImGui

[image]

Above picture shows the sample of displaying from the webcam feed using ESCAPI.
refer https://github.com/jarikomppa/escapi/ for more details.

Comment: If you want to know more https://abdullahfarwees.blogspot.com/2023/01/video-display-in-imgui-using-c-and.html

Answer (score 0):

I once developed an application using imgui that displayed video via imgui, and it did work, but there was performance limitations. If you dont need to display more than 8 feeds at a time, you should be okay.

You'll need an appsink on your gst pipeline, and then in the appsink you need to pull the gstbuffer and convert it to a GL texture, then pass the GL texture to imgui.

You can reference this repo, its the same one i used as a starting block:

https://github.com/tbeloqui/gst-imgui